# Which is the better benchmarking strategy: local machine vs remote machine

Tags: jmeter, benchmarking

today I had a debate which is the better benchmarking strategy: local machine vs remote machine. And I would like to know some other opinions on that topic. It is more general question, but in this case it was a java project.

The test was about how well some template engines perform.
After a warming up phase of 30 seconds the benchmark runs 120 seconds with 100 threads.

The tested page has some static and dynamic parts. like random items in a table and list, but a static header for example (no database operations).

**Senario 1**:

The webserver and the benchmarking tools runs on the same machine.
The tests were made with ab and jmeter.

Pro arguments:

- the production would also be not an ideal system.
- other java process may also run on the production system.
- even if the benchmarking tools slow down the result in average the results are still valid ( the better technology would be better on any variant)

Con arguments:

- the same machine tries to beat itself
- benchmarks slow down real performance

**Senario 2**:

A remote machine tests the other system:

Pro arguments:

- one system can try to reach the limits of the other
- benchmarks (jmeter) does not run on the same jvm

Con arguments:

- production system would not be an ideal environment
- network may slow down the results

First I would like to know which is the better way to go. Second if some of the arguments are not valid. Or in the end it doesn't even matter. And I would like to know other arguments for any of both variants. I hope this   question does not get closed, because I think it is not to general. One option must be the better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scenario 2, in almost all cases, is going to be closer to production behavior.  I would argue that the cons listed for Scenario 1 effectively invalidate any of the results.  However, as long as you are consistent with the approach you should be able to use results for comparisons even if they do not match what you expect to see from production.

Addressing the cons of Scenario 2:

- Production System would not be an ideal environment.

If you are about to load test production, something else is wrong to begin with.

- Network may slow down results.

While this might be true, the networking for a distributed internal test environment is still better than your customers will have from external sources.  In almost all cases you will want to do bandwidth network simulations to ensure production-like behavior.

To accomplish this, look for the following line in the jmeter.properties file:

```
# Define characters per second > 0 to emulate slow connections
#httpclient.socket.http.cps=0
#httpclient.socket.https.cps=0
```

This will limit the "bandwidth" of each JMeter thread. *(quoted because the throttling does not happen at the network level)*  Do a simple study to see what CPS means in terms of your applications.

---

The Short Answer:

Always try to test in a distributed setup because you have more flexibility.  Also, consider the scenario where you need multiple load generator machines to actually stress a target.  In that case you have no choice at all, so I would argue  "best practice" is to configure isolated test environments with separate load generator machines.

Also, to effectively maximize the output of each load generator machine it is advised to customize open file descriptor limits (ulimits) and JVM memory settings for the load generator machines.  In most cases those configurations are not acceptable for application servers.

Hope that helps, please let me know if I can elaborate further,
-Addled

Comment: How about the point that the better technology would be better on any variant? (even if the benchmarking tools slow down the result in average the results are still valid)

Comment: Yeah, so in general as long as you use the same approach between versions your results should be valid for comparison.

However, keep in mind that you may not hit the right software bottlenecks if you are sharing hardware for testing and target.

Also, when your results are much faster than customers see in production it gets difficult to turn your results over to business units because they say "but our customers are seeing 3 seconds!"  You then have to try to explain how your test environment is much faster than production, which is a conversation I try to avoid at all costs.

Comment: So why the overhead of making a remote test , when the results indicate the same? That sound like variant 1 should be the choice (even with i agree with you)

Comment: In practice option 1 is not even an option.  For some larger JMeter tests that simulate 100,000 concurrent users I have a set of over 50 load generators hitting a single application cluster.

In that scenario there is no option 1 to consider.

Comment: Can you name one example of right software bottlenecks, which came to your mind ?

Comment: Sure - Lets say in production your application VM is 8 gig memory.  In order to test all of that on a single node, you made a VM with 16 gig memory, and allocated the usual amount to the application server, and set aside some for jmeter.  You just fundamentally changed the architecture of your application.  One could argue that the application server should not ever have capacity to be running JMeter.

Comment: Okay thank you very much. I mark you answer tomorrow. An unanswered question may lead to another opinion. So i would like to keep it unanswered until tomorrow.

Comment: You're most welcome, glad I might have been some help!